# move_base functionality

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I find a move_base functionality scheme?
I want something more detailed than this

I did this scheme

[image: image description]

this is more complete

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274572/move_base-functionality/) by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
Could you please attach the image you linked to in your comment to your question directly? I've give you enough karma to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's all on the documentation here:
http://wiki.ros.org/move_base

The scheme itself (taken from there) would be:
https://imgur.com/a/AObhV
(Can't upload images yet.)

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on 2017-10-31**:
ok but I won't something more detailed like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3k643xqv6l5n996/move_base_schema.png?dl=0

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
@pietrocolombo: that is a flow chart diagram, which is something different from a 'functionality scheme' (which is a bit ambiguous in any case).